# Which problems can stem from overriding java.util.HashSets contains()-method?

Tags: java, overriding, contains, hashset

I want to use a `HashSet` to store some objects:

```
public class StoredObject{
    Type type; //Type is an enum
    //other fields

    Type getType(){return type;}
}
```

Now, I want to store only one `StoredObject` of the same `Type`, so I override `contains()` in a subclass of `HashSet`:

```
public MySet<E extends StoredObject> extends java.util.HashSet<E>{
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        if(StoredObject.class.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {//if o implements StoredObject
            for(StoredObject s : this) {
                if(s.getType() == ((StoredObject) o).getType()) return true;
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Before this I wanted to use `HashSet` and modify the `equals()` of `StoredObject`. However, the way above seems like a shorter and safer way, especially as in my case the stored objects all implement an interface and don't extend the same class.

Now my question: Is this implementation safe? I tried to search for things it could break, but did not find any. I read that overriding `equals()` can break Collections.
Also, does this subclass defeats the purpose of an `HashSet`, since it does not use the `HashMap` for `contains()`?

Comment: "does this subclass defeats the purpose of a HashSet"?—Yes it does. You can write your own separate set implementation if you need to.

Comment: Instead of creating a subclass of HashSet, instead override equals and hashcode on your StoredObject class to use Type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashMap<Type,StoredObject>` is the appropriate collection for this.

If you override `equals(Object)` then you must also override `hashCode` (it's also not a bad idea to make it implement `Comparable` and perhaps override `toString`). Use the `@Override` annotation to ensure you have the right parameter types and spelling - very easy to get wrong and confusing to debug.

What can go wrong?

- There's a lot of methods in `HashSet` to override, so that's a lot of work.
- More methods may be added to `HashSet` in future versions of Java - how are you going to look out for this?
- `contains` should be an O(1) operation (assuming a good distribution of hash codes), but the OP implementation is O(n).
- `Set.equals` on another `Set` will report incorrect results.

Note also that `StoredObject.class.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())` is better written as `o instanceof StoredObject` (assuming you've got `isAssignableFrom` the right way around).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the appropiate collection for this. While further working on this problem I found that using `Enum Map` is even simpler in the case that `Type` is an enum, like I have.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this implementation safe?

Absolutely not. There are other methods on `HashSet` that wouldn't work correctly, e.g. `add()`, leaving the size of the set incorrect.

Besides, that implementation would totally ruin the performance of the `contains` method, making it run in *O(n)* instead of *O(1)*.

If you need a `Set` with a definition of equality that differs from the objects natural definition as implemented by `equals()` and `hashCode()`, use a `TreeSet` and supply a custom `Comparator`.

```java
class MySet<E extends StoredObject> extends java.util.TreeSet<E> {
    public MySet() {
        super(Comparator.comparing(StoredObject::getType));
    }
}
```

I do agree with [Tom Hawtin - tackline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63970185/5221149), that `HashMap<Type, StoredObject>` is a better option, because it allows you to get the `StoredObject` for a given `Type`, which is otherwise very difficult to do with a `Set`. It also allows you to check for existence given just a `Type`, without having to create a dummy `StoredObject` object for the check.